# Opening example newsletter opens popup twice

Tags: bug, user-interface, newsletter, popups

When I´m on Workplace and not logged in and click on the button "see an example" to get a preview of the newsletter, then the Popup is opened twice and I have to close it 2 times via "x".

This is hard to test and to reproduce, cause the section "Did you find this question interesting?" is not always displayed.

[image]

[image]